# Записать параметры и значения URL в массив

Tags: запрос, url, asp.net-core-2

С бэк-энда написанном на *ASP .NET Core 2.0* приходит такой адресс:

> catalog/search?mtype=1&brand=8&model=7&g=1&g=2&g=103&g=104&region=0&town=0

Мне нужно вытащить параметры и их значения после **?**.
Уже есть довольно много решений этой задачи, только у меня переменная **g** перезаписывает значения, вместо добавления их в массив.

Нужно:
g: "[1, 2, 103, 104]"

И дело в том, что с формы у меня отправляется name=g[], но ASP .NET Core 2.0 откидает [] из-за этого и вся проблема. Так бы оно само записывало в массив.

Пользуюсь этой функцией:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){
    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение через проверку на соотвествие параметра и создание для него массива:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function() {
      var vars = [], hash, groups = [];   // создал массив /groups/
      var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

      for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
          hash = hashes[i].split('=');
          if (hash[0] == 'g') {           // если параметр == 'g'
              groups.push(hash[1]);       // записываем его значение
              vars[hash[0]] = groups;     // для ключа задаем значения массива
          }
          else {                          // иначе
              vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];    // записываем по-умолчанию (как перем.)
          }
      }
      return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name) {
      return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  }
});
console.log($.getUrlVars());
</script>
```